# Using transform of a random variable to find expectation

Tags: probability

My book says that in order to find the expectation of a random variable $X$ you can take the derivative of its transform $M_X(s) = E[e^{sx}]$ with respect to $s$ at 0.

However, I wanted to test this for what I thought would be an easy case. Let $X$ be a uniform random variable in $[0, 1]$. Then
$$ M_X(s) = \int_0^1 e^{sx} dx = \frac{e^s - 1}{s}.$$

Then to find the expectation we take the derivative
$$ E[X] = \left. \frac{d}{ds} M_X(s)\right|_{s = 0} = \left. \frac{s^2e^s - e^s + 1}{s^2}\right|_{s = 0}. $$

I do not see how I can get to $1/2$ from here though. The derivative is not defined at 0, correct? Does this only work when $M_x(s)$ is differentiable at 0? The book kind of made it seem like it should always simplify, but I don't see it.

Comment: The error is in the computation of the derivative. The answer should be $\frac{(s-1)\exp(s) + 1}{s^2}$, whose limit is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ah thanks. I figured I did something silly like that. Damn constant becoming a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in the computation. If you are computing the derivative at $s\ne 0$, the first term in the numerator  should be $se^s$.

But technically this does not give the derivative **at** $0$. However, if you take the limit of the corrected expression as $s\to 0$, you will get the right number $1/2$. For example you can find the limit using L'Hospital's Rule twice.

However, it is best to get the first derivative, and the higher derivatives, at $s=0$ by writing down the power series expansion of $\dfrac{e^s-1}{s}$.